# Google Maps API - Get Results from ALL matching locations

Tags: google-maps

Currently our system brings back listings from an area in the specified location. So if I enter a postcode, it will use the bounds and bring back local listings. This works fine.

However if I search for 'Newcastle' it will default to Newcastle Tyneside rather than Newcastle under Lyme.

Is there a way to tell the maps API to not use whichever it considers 'default' and to bring back listings from ALL locations?

Below is the basic script I'm using to geocode the address:

```
var address = "<?php echo $_GET['place']." UK";?>";
///set map center position and place marker
geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status) {
///set center position
map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
circ = new google.maps.Circle();
circ.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
circ.setRadius(miles * 1609.0);
map.fitBounds(circ.getBounds());
circ.setMap(map);

// Set co-ordinates of address
var addresslong = results[0].geometry.location.lat();
var addresslat = results[0].geometry.location.lng();
var addresslatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(addresslong, addresslat);        
placeMarkers(addresslatlng);
```

Any help or advice would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the results object brings back more than one location. Iterate through all the objects in results.

Comment: I think I see what you mean - I'll have a look